# WPF Image gets cropped (right side) even though Stretch property is set to Uniform

Tags: c#, wpf

Title says it all: I have a UserControl with an Image with its Source bound to a BitmapImage in the view model. Even though I have the stretch property set to uniform, the image's right side gets clipped (the image's aspect ratio is not the same as the on on the Image object). I want the image to keep its aspect ratio, but  without clipping (ie: with padding of white or black). What am I doing wrong?

PS: I know the BitmapImage in the ViewModel is correct because if I save it to disk I get the full image, no clipping

```
<GroupBox Header="Image Stream"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
          Grid.Column="1"
          Width="{StaticResource ResourceKey=streamImageWidth}" 
          Height="{StaticResource ResourceKey=streamImageHeight}">
    <Image Source="{Binding StreamImage}" Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="Both"></Image>
</GroupBox>
```

Comment: My guess would be that you're using a StackPanel. But how are we supposed to tell that when you don't show us your code?

Comment: @Clemens thanks for taking the time to address this issue.

I am not using a StackPanel at the moment. The Image is just one of many controls, but basically what I have is a main Window with a grid control. Inside of that grid control, on one of the rows I have a TabControl. One of the TabItems of that TabControl contains a UserControl which in turn has another Grid. One of the columns of this Grid is a GroupBox and finally inside that groupbox you have the Image.

Comment: Please do not post your XAML as comment. Edit your question instead.

Comment: @Clemens I have re-posted the XAML on the question itselt. Deleting the comment

Comment: That's certainly not all of the relevant XAML. Anyway, it looks odd that you explicitly set the GroupBox's Width and Height. For what reason? If it's the child of a Grid, you would usually not do that, and also don't change HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment.

Comment: @Clemens I have been experimenting quite a bit trying to make this work. I have tried removing them from the GroupBox and setting them on the Grid's row/col definition; the behaviour remains unchanged

Comment: As said, do not set Width, Height, HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment. Also don't set Stretch and StretchDirection of the Image. Uniform and Both are the default values anyway.

Comment: @Clemens as I said in the last comment I have removed the width and height properties from the GroupBox, and set them on the Grid's row and column definitions. I have also removed Horizontal and Vertical alignment from the group box, and the stretch properties from the Image. The behaviour remains the same

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, sorry. It works fine for me. There must be something you haven't shown in your question.

Comment: @Clemens I have finally managed to get it working, but I still do not fully understand the issue. Basically the grid with the Image was inside a custom UserControl, and in the MainWindow this was included with a specified Width. Removing the Width property from the UserControl made everything work. Thank you for the time you dedicated to this issue

Although I would like to better understand what was going on, I understand if there is not enough information on the issue to do.
You can close the task at will; I might try to replicate this later on on a small project and create another issue